# Resizable window + Vertical splitter?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

I have a resizable window using jQuery-UI, but I want to have a vertical splitter between two divs in the window as shown by this example here: http://methvin.com/splitter/vbasic.html

The problem is that the libraries will conflict with each other and give weird results while resizing the window, right? Does anyone know of any libraries for flexible, dynamic window sizes?